# team foundation integration with selenium and specflow

Tags: c#, selenium, testing, tfs, nunit

I want to integrate Specflow tests based on Selenium with Team foundation server. Which unit test framework i must use to do this? I use Nunit and after build is completed on TFS i receive: "No test runs are available for this build." on Test Results section. I use VS studio 2015

Answer (score 3):

Do you have  the Visual Studio Test Adapter for NUnit installed?

If you use  the latest  version of NUnit on Nuget this is handled for you. If not you need to explicitly install the adapter.

If the Visual Studio Test Runner (the one built into VS) picks up your tests then the build will too.

Comment: Though I recommend adding it as a NuGet package to the test project and not installing the vsix on the build server (or adding them to the Build Controller's binaries path. Add this package to your project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NUnitTestAdapter/

Answer (score -2):

Why not simply use MSTest instead of NUnit? This is the native way in TFS. Simply mark up your test cases with `[TestMethod]` and you're fine. The `TestMethodAttribute` class is defined in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting`.